# using jq : how can i use the same search in other field without duplicate code?

Tags: json, field, jq

I have the following json file for exemple:

```
{
    "FOO": {
        "name": "Donald",
        "location": "Stockholm"
    },
    "BAR": {
        "name": "Walt",
        "location": "Stockholm"
    },
    "BAZ": {
        "name": "Jack",
        "location": "Whereever"
    }
}
```

and i have this jq command :

```
cat json | jq .[] | {newname : select(.location=="Stockholm") | .name , contains_w : select(.location=="Stockholm") | .name  | startswith("W")}
```

so i get the result :

```
{
  "newname": "Donald",
  "contains_w": false
}
{
  "newname": "Walt",
  "contains_w": true
}
```

my question is : is there any way to `DRY` my command ? 
i mean how can i get the same result without **duplicate** the part :

```
select(.location=="Stockholm") | .name
```

how can i reuse the result of **newname** feild ?

i have a really big file to work with so i don't want to waste time and resources.

Comment: @Oguz_Ismail - Please undelete your answer!!!

Comment: @Ismail why did you delete your answer ? it was really helpful

Comment: @SoufianeELH - He probably deleted it because you seemed to change the question.  Please revise your question as necessary so that if there is a correct and worthy answer, you are prepared to "accept" it.

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering multiple times during object construction. You could filter first and then do the construction on the filtered list eg.

```
map(select(.location=="Stockholm")) 
  | map({newname: .name, contains_w: (.name | startswith("W"))})
```

https://jqplay.org/s/aXjlgOEDnb